# How many non-parametric Cannonball Numbers are there?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I got totally nerd sniped by this Numberphile video featuring Matt Parker:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6L06pyt9CA&pp=ygURY2Fubm9uYmFsbCBudW1iZXI%3D. Basically, he searches for numbers such that if you gathered that number of cannonballs together, you could form them into either an n-sided regular polygon or a pyramid with a base of n sides (so you could write it as the sum of consecutive n-sided polygonal numbers). Matt himself admitted his code was not ideal so I wrote my own Python code to try to find more and went to multiple websites to do some research on them. The first thing I found from reading this OEIS entry (https://oeis.org/A027696)is that there are infinitely many "parametric" cannonball numbers. If you take a side number $n\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ that is greater than 5 and plug it into this equation

$C_n=\frac{1}{162}\left(n^{7}-14n^{6}+66n^{5}-91n^{4}-133n^{3}+309n^{2}+70n-38\right)$

you are guaranteed to get a parametric cannonball number. This means there are infinitely many such solutions. Apart from the fact that this comes from a cool-looking 7th-degree polynomial with 7 real roots that can all be written in an exact form (mildly interesting-comes from the ability to factor it into two quadratics and a cubic) and that the last digits of these numbers in base 10 repeat in the pattern 5,5,1,1,1,5,5,1,1,1... (easy but annoying to prove), these numbers don't interest me very much unless someone can convince me otherwise. The non-parametric ones are incredibly strange though. I ran my code for 19 hours on sides less than a million and found 40 of them which I have listed in the answer section along with some interesting tidbits about the special ones.

However, I still have questions about these. The main one is if these are the only ones out there. I searched quite hard, especially through cannonball numbers with less than 100 sides and I could not find more. However, my code may not be entirely optimal and I ran it on a 2020 Macbook Pro which I use for work, and not a giant PC or supercomputer that I could let sit idly for months. More generally I would like to know if there are any discernible patterns in these numbers. They are a lot more sporadic and randomly distributed than the parametric ones and I couldn't find anything resembling order except that they all end in 0, 1, 5, or 6 (again, why can these ones end in 0 or 6 while the parametric ones can't and why don't they seem to end with 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, or 9?). The resources about these numbers seem scarce and what is out there either discusses the n=3 and n=4 cases or is so obtuse that I can't wrap my head around it. This paper seems to be the best example of research into these numbers: [https://www2.math.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~mkaneko/papers/kaneko-tachibana.pdf](https://www2.math.kyushu-u.ac.jp/%7Emkaneko/papers/kaneko-tachibana.pdf). The math is far too advanced for a physics student like me to understand and the author never seems to provide a list like mine despite the fact that he published the aforementioned OEIS sequence. So to anyone who is as interested in this problem as I am, I would love to see what you can do with it. I am also happy to share my code if anyone is interested in that.

Answer (score 1):

Four 3-cannonball numbers: 10,120,1540,7140 (proven to be the only such 4 by E.T. Avanesov in 1967-if you write your own code to find these this is a good test case to work on. Finding any more than these ones means your code probably encountered a floating point error like my early attempts did)

One 4-cannonball number: 4900 (the original example found - proven to be the only such one by G.N. Watson in 1918)

One 6-cannonball number: 946

Three 8-cannonball numbers: 5985, 123395663059845, 774611255177760 (the last one is my favorite of them all-look how huge it is for such a small number of sides!)

Two 10-cannonball numbers: 175, 368050005576

Two 11-cannonball numbers: 1519937678700, 7248070597636 (this is the largest number of sides that I found with more than one non-parametric solution)

14-cannonball number: 441

17: 1580765544996

30: 23001

41: 55202400

43: 245905

50: 314755

60: 1785508245600 (This is the last one that actually exceeds the size the parametric formula predicts)

88: 48280

145: 101337426

276: 801801

322: 1169686

374: 15064335000

823: 197427385

1152: 149979784926720

2378: 432684460

2386: 29437553530

4980: 24264913354964425

9325: 3176083959788026

9525: 16195753597485

16420: 913053565546276

19605: 5519583702676

31265: 90525801730 (this one was highlighted in the Numberphile Video)

31368: 17147031694579605

83135: 31148407558500

125070: 890348736143873526 (the biggest one I found)

210903: 10290361955160

223613: 421687634347915 (the largest number of sides I found-imagine a regular polygon with 223613 sides or a pyramid with 223613 sides on its base!)

UPDATE from 2024: I found one more! This one blows the others out of the water in both size and side number. I found this one in a different way; I did not brute force it because that would have taken forever with my code. If anyone finds this thread and is interested I will explain what I did. Regardless, I checked that it works on Wolfram Alpha so here it is:

191070870-sided cannonball number with 240845063989967856315 cannonballs. This is about 241 quintillion! This is close to the lower bound for the number of grains of sand on earth-extraordinarily large.